# Newish book with a sister and brother who live in a domed, floating continent

Tags: story-identification, novel

I can’t recall a title. Found a book around 2015-2018 at B&N in new sci-fi.

Sister and brother live in a kingdom of post-end-of-days(?) where a dome is covering their floating continent. People use elemental crystals and flying harnesses to combat demons that break through, and train against other towns in competition within kingdom. Main character uses fire, and I think is given the nickname 'Phoenix?' Each kid is super gifted because of experiments done on parents.

Cover was red, I believe. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like it could be the *[The Seraphim](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?40318)* series by David Dalgleish. The first book is called *[Skyborn](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1915338)*, and includes most of the elements in the question.

From the cover blurb:

> The last remnants of humanity live on six islands floating high above
> the Endless Ocean, fighting a brutal civil war in the skies. The
> Seraphim, elite soldiers trained for aerial combat, battle one another
> while wielding elements of ice, fire and lightning.
>
> The lives of their parents claimed in combat, twins Kael and Breanna
> Skyborn enter the Seraphim Academy to follow in their footsteps. There
> they will learn to harness the elements as weapons and fight at
> break-neck speeds while soaring high above the waters. But they must
> learn quickly, for a nearby island has set its hungry eyes upon their
> home. When the invasion comes, the twins must don their wings and
> ready their blades to save those they love from annihilation.

Their weapons are indeed powered by elemental crystals.

The next book in the series, *[Fireborn](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2068077)*, deals with a rebellion against forces that have invaded the protagonists' island, and Bree becomes nicknamed the "Phoenix" because of the burning twin blades she uses in battle.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you!